# Are javascript's async functions actually synchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to figure out how does asynchronous code work in Javascript. Now, I understand that there is actually one single thread in JS that executes jobs in a queue, and it can only start executing the next job if the current one is completed (i.e. if all of the sync code or an async function is completed).

Now, the confusing part is what actually counts as an asynchronous function - what actually gets put into a separate job in the queue, and what doesn't.

For start, we have the `async` keyword for functions. So does that mean those functions will be put into a separate job in the queue and be executed somewhere in the future? Well, actually it turns out the answer is **NO**. But bear with me, as I will explain.

As far as I understand, in theory, the JS thread is supposed to begin by executing all synchronous code until it completes, while delaying the execution of all async functions, promises and callbacks by placing them as jobs to the end of the queue. Then, once all sync code completes, it will start doing all those jobs that got piled up.

So if I have the following code:

```
async function asyncFunc() {
    console.log("executing async function");
}

console.log("starting sync code");
asyncFunc().then(() => {
    console.log("executing callback of async function")
});
console.log("sync code completed");
```

Then in theory, it should execute all sync code first, and only then start executing the async function and then the callback:

```
starting sync code
sync code completed
executing async function
executing callback of async function
```

But the reality is different! In reality, it actually executes the async function *synchronously*, together with the rest of the sync code. The only bit that actually gets put into the job queue is the *callback* of the async function:

```
starting sync code
executing async function
sync code completed
executing callback of async function
```

So what does that mean? That `async` functions are actually a lie? It seems so, as they are actually *normal, synchronous* functions that you can happen to attach an *async* callback to.

Now, I know that `async` is actually a syntactic sugar for a function that returns a `Promise`, such as:

```
async function asyncFunc() {
    console.log("executing async function");
}
```

is syntactic sugar for:

```
function asyncFunc() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log("executing async function");
        resolve();
    });
}
```

But my point still remains. The supposedly-async function that you pass into the promise actually is executed synchronously. Well, technically the `Promise` object doesn't imply that it will be executed asynchronously, but the `async` keyword does! So it's outright false information, it makes you believe that it's asynchronous, when it demonstrably isn't.

Comment: Your `asyncFunc` is actually a synonym to `function asyncFunc() { console.log("executing async function"); return new Promise(); }` So there is no lie - it's just not doing what you thought it was.

Comment: If you write an `async` function that never calls `await`, then yes, this is no surprise. The `async/await` syntax is really just that: a syntactic convenience for managing the problem of chains of `.then()` callback code with plain Promise objects.

Comment: It's still a lie, because having `async` in front of the function implies that the _whole body_ of the function is executed asynchronously, while it isn't.

Comment: You have misunderstood the intention of the `async/await` syntax.

Comment: @MauriceNino No, nothing in JS is run in parallel, as there is only 1 thread. I actually tried adding a 5-second "busy wait" loop to the sync code after the async function is called. It executes the async function immediately, and only after 5 seconds it executes the callback.

Comment: Really the best way to think about `async` as being a sort of "type" declaration that tells JavaScript "this function returns one or more Promise objects". The parser can then build the code for the function as a *generator* function, with each internal `await` expression really meaning a `yield` of another Promise.

Comment: @YevgeniN while it's true that they don't run in parallel, JS doesn't have only one thread. Workers are a prime example of multithreading. "JavaScript is single-threaded" is an over-simplification of the fact that user code (outside the browser internals) is run on the main UI thread.

Comment: @YevgeniN I have posted a snippet of what I mean with that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just like when constructing a Promise, anything synchronous inside an `async` function *before any `await`s* are encountered will execute synchronously. An `async` function will only stop executing its code once it encounters an `await` - until then, it may as well be a normal non-`async` function (except for the fact that it'll wrap the return value in a Promise).

```js
async function asyncFunc2() {
  console.log("in Async function 2");
}
async function asyncFunc1() {
  console.log("in Async function 1");
  await asyncFunc2();
  console.log('After an await');
}
console.log("starting sync code");
asyncFunc1().then(() => {
  console.log("Received answer from async code");
});
console.log("finishing sync code");
```

As you can see in the snippet above, the main thread only resumes outside of `asyncFunc1` once `asyncFunc1`'s `await` (and all *synchronous* code invoked by that `await`) is complete.

`async` is a keyword that allows you to use `await` inside of a function, but it doesn't *intrinsically* mean anything else, really - it's just a keyword. The function *may* even run all of its code synchronously (though that'd be kind of weird to see).

Comment: Actually, that seems to be wrong also. It executes the code after an `await` synchronously as well. Example:

```javascript
async function asyncFunc2() {
    console.log("in Async func 2");
}

async function asyncFunc1() {
    console.log("in Async func 1");
    await asyncFunc2();
}

console.log("starting sync code");
asyncFunc1().then(() => {
    console.log("Received answer from async code");
});
console.log("finishing sync code");
```

Output:

```javascript
starting sync code
in Async func 1
in Async func 2
finishing sync code
Received answer from async code
```

Comment: Nowhere in there are you waiting until *after* an `await` to log things, so you see `finishing sync code` at the end, just before the Promise resolves and the `Received answer from async code` - your functions may as well be a `return Promise.resolve()`. It's only when something is done *after* an `await` that you'll see those things being done after the lower sync code is done

Comment: Yeah, so that makes them not truly "asynchronous" functions, but "asynchronous-only-after-the-line-with-an-await-keyword-if-it-exists" functions.

Comment: @YevgeniN I think you should read more into what `async/await` actually is. The first await is where the `return new Promise ...` part would be

Comment: @YevgeniN Yep, that's a pretty precise way of putting it. You can put a `Promise.resolve().then(asyncFunc1)` to run stuff only after all synchronous lower code is done

Answer (score 1):

Just to prove mine and @CertainPerformance's point.
Here is the same example with a sleep function that waits 500ms before resolving that is awaited:

```js
async function sleep(msec) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, msec));
}

async function asyncFunc() {
  await sleep(500);
  console.log("executing async function");
}

console.log("starting sync code");
asyncFunc().then(() => {
  console.log("executing callback of async function")
});
console.log("sync code completed");
```

And here with just a console.log:

```js
async function sleep(msec) {
  console.log('test');
} 

async function asyncFunc() {
  await sleep(500);
  console.log("executing async function");
}

console.log("starting sync code");
asyncFunc().then(() => {
  console.log("executing callback of async function")
});
console.log("sync code completed");
```

Comment: Yes, this works because `setTimeout` always schedules a new job. That seems to be the only way to force code to execute asynchronously. But if, for example, you replace `setTimeout(resolve, msec)` with just a `console.log`, it will still call it synchronously.

Comment: I mean that the `console.log` itself will be called synchronously. I see now that only the code after the line with an `await` keyword is actually called asynchronously.