# Async await function result in js

Tags: javascript, async-await, event-loop

Please tell me why in this code:

```
function print() {
   console.log("1");
 }
   console.log("2");

 async function foo() {
   console.log("3");
   await print();
   console.log("4");
 }

 foo();

 console.log(5);
```

**Output is: 2 3 1 5 4**
**But not:  2 3 1 4 5**

What's reason?

see above

I expected that result : **But not:  2 3 1 4 5**
But **Output is: 2 3 1 5 4**

Comment: await is not what you are trying to use here and what you think, it doesn't make the code concurrent by default, please read a couple of articles about async/await in javascript.

Comment: Because you forgot to `await` the call to `foo()`.  Note also that `await`-ing the call to `print()` does exactly nothing because `print()` is not `async` nor does it return anything awaitable.  Basically... Just remove all of the `async` and `await` from this code in the first place and you'll get the output you want.

Comment: @David - Not *exactly* nothing (it adds an async tick), but exactly nothing *useful*. :-)

Comment: `foo();` is an async call. You cannot expect it to finish *before* the next line. This example right here is really, really bad to generalise from, since there is almost nothing async happening but there is an async function. Overall, it works *almost* like a sync code except for an extremely tiny bit. The whole example is more confusing than it needs to be and could have been a lot simpler.

Comment: it's task from interview question :)

Comment: Being from an interview doesn't make it a good question.

Comment: Also relevant to this question: [When does async function actually return a pending promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67769474) | [Are javascript's async functions actually synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57906002) | [What are asynchronous functions in JavaScript? What is "async" and "await" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62196932) | [Does awaiting a non-Promise have any detectable effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55262996)